# Access field from generic List in GetRange() method?

Tags: c#, generic-list

Does anybody know how to access a specific field from List<>? I cant figure out howto access a specific field in newList object.

```
  List<Liner> LX = new List<Liner>();

  public class Liner
  {
      public double Temperature { get; set; }
      public double Moisture { get; set; }
  }

newList = LX.OrderBy(x => x.Temperature).ToList();

var lstMXLast = newList.GetRange(8755, 5);  // I need only 5 specific Moisture records in this case.
```

Comment: @Nikhil http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/21k0e39c.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`GetRange`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/21k0e39c.aspx) returns a copy of the list with the given range. So your list needs at least 8760 items. To select only the `Moisture` property of your objects, you can use LINQ's [`Select`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.select.aspx):

```
var lstMoistures = newList.GetRange(8755, 5).Select(l => l.Moisture).ToList();
```

Note: you need the `ToList` at the end only if you want to persist the query. Your `ToList` at the end of the `OrderBy` query is useless because you want to chain another query. I would materialze LINQ queries only as late as possible.

You could also use LINQ for the whole thing:

```
var lstMoistures = newList.Skip(8755).Take(5).Select(l => l.Moisture).ToList();
```

Assuming that you originally wanted to select the 5 liners with the highest temperature, this should give you the correct result:

```
var lstMoistures = LX.OrderByDescending(x => x.Temperature).Take(5).Select(l => l.Moisture).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `newList.GetRange(8755, 5).Select(l => l.Moisture)` to just get the `Moisture` component from the five selected `Liner` records.

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
var results = newList.GetRange(8755, 5).Select(m => m.Moisture);
```

It will give you moisture levels of `Liner` returned by `GetRange()` i.e. 5 moisture levels.